# Constructing a graph in tensorflow-java using OperationBuilder class in Java

Tags: java, tensorflow

Hi I am following the official tensorflow example of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java 
to construct my computation graph inside java instead of using a one constructed in python. I see that they construct a graph for preprocessing the image which does not require any backproagation. So my question is, if I want to construct a computation graph for complete training do I follow the same steps(create static APIs for the ops) , or do I need to do something more in order to manage the gradients for backpropagation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow Java bindings don't have support for automatic differentiation. You can compute gradients yourself, by manually adding appropriate operations, but there is no magic like `tf.gradients()` in python that will add them for you.

Comment: So does that mean that the C backend does not support autodiff and it's entirely handled by Python ? If that's the case then how is training possible in Java ? I don't see any gradients code in the Java bindings repo . So if c does not support auto diff then how is Java training happening? Thanks

Comment: Originally, all gradients (the set of operations that compute the gradient) were in Python. Some were moved to C++ core now (e.g. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3d8a0538c1d75142c381a5c169ef0696cb95b4ec/tensorflow/core/ops/nn_grad.cc#L68) but not all. TensorFlow does not really support training in anything other than Python now. Other language bindings are primarily for inference/serving.

Comment: I'd rephrase iga's statement a bit. Python is most suitable for *constructing* graphs. But you can execute any graph (training or inference) in other languages.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. On debugging I found that indeed the autodiff logic is implemented in python and not part of the C++ logic . I wonder if tensorflow has any plans to port it to C++ core as well. This way any of the client languages can have their generated APIs to call the backend C++ code.

Comment: There is a function in the C API to construct the gradient graph: [`TF_AddGradients`](.https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L1127). Hooking that function up to the Java API should be relatively simple. However, this relies on the gradient functions for each TensorFlow operation to be ported to C++. While many operations have been ported, not all have. Instructions on porting are [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/cc/gradients)